# CSS transition with filters leads to visual problems

Tags: css, filter, css-transitions, transition

Here is an example where you can see the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/bqwacfah/

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: all;
}

img:hover {
  filter: brightness(300%);
}

.image1 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px hsl(205, 100%, 50%);
}

.image2 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px hsl(205, 60%, 20%);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: all;
}

div:hover {
  filter: brightness(300%);
}

.div1 {
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  color: hsl(205, 100%, 50%);
}

.div2 {
  background-color: hsl(200, 60%, 20%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  color: hsl(205, 60%, 20%);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <img class="image1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Jupiter_by_Cassini-Huygens.jpg">
  <img class="image2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Jupiter_by_Cassini-Huygens.jpg">
  <br />
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>

</body>
```

I have tested it with the actual Chrome 56. On the RIGHT side everything works fine.

On the LEFT side you will notice that ...

1. while hovering the hue of the color changes towards green
2. at the end of the transition the hue/color of the div and the box-shadow is the same
3. shortly before the end of the transition the box-shadow is sort of blown out, but directly after the transition it looks good.
4. when the transition is done and you move the mouse off the div, the box-shadow immediately gets blown out

Is there any solution or workaround to avoid these problems instead of choosing a dark base color?

Comment: 1-The reason for changing the color is 300% `brightness`. 2- you assigned `margin:30px` to `img` so 30px around the `img` is count as image and hover acts on that too. Delete `margin` or define a parent for `<img>` and assign `margin` to the parent. 3-When 2 solve it will solve too. 4- Change  `transition-duration: 2s` to `transition: all 2s ease-in-out`

Comment: @ata [1] sure, but brightness should change just the luminocity, not the hue. The hue of the images does not shift. [2] I mean the hue of the div itself (205) and the hue of the box-shadow (200) .. it has nothing to do with margin but my explaination [4] done, but no difference

Comment: [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqwacfah/1/) solved `<img>`s problem.

Comment: @ata It is a good workaround that does not apply the filter to the box-shadow. Sadly this is exact what I want. ;-) But why does the hue change? A bug or a feature?!

Comment: Good it works. About changing hue I'm not sure but adding a little white and yellow color to blue, turns it to green as you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) the color you picked `hsl(205,100%,20%)` is not a dim blue color and it contains some yellow. If you choose for example `hsl(240,100%,20%)` there is no such an effect.